# Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::attempt does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, spa

estoy tratando de usar la autenticacion de una SPA con passport en laravel.
segui todos los pasos de este tuto pero al final me da error.
estoy usando la version 6 de laravel y me spa esta en vue.
estoy usando las rutas web.

```html
//este es mi user.php

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
```

```html
//este es mi AuthServicesPrivider.php

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Passport::routes();
    }
```

```html
//mi auth.php

'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

```html
//mis rutas 

Auth::routes();


Passport::routes(function($router){
    $router->forAccessTokens();
});


Route::resource('/add','AddMoviesController');
```

siempre que intento enviar datos ya sea para el loggin o para crear un nuevo registro me envia este error. para el login solo envia el error y no hace mas nada pero para el registro envia el error y la dbase los datos si se guardan.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En `auth.php` le pusiste `'driver' => 'passport',` a `web` y va en `api`. En web deja `'driver' => 'session',`. Puedes seguir las instrucciones de Passport en la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport#installation)

Comment: mil gracias amigo. funciono.